# C# Unable to return property dynamically from entity class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm using entity framework and I'm attempting to return a property from an instance of one of the entity classes representing a table in my database. I keep getting a `null` value returned. Does it not work on entity classes? I found a couple posts about it on this site and followed them as best I could but to no avail.

I have something like the following:

```
string propName = "name";
var itemID = object.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(object, null);
```

If I replace the `.GetProperty().GetValue()` part with `.GetProperties()` I can successfully see all the properties of the object, but when I attempt to get a value from an individual property it's returning `null` even though there is a value in that field.

Comment: What is `object`? Do you mean `someObject`? Do your `someObject` have a `name` public property?

Comment: object is an instance of my entity class and the string variable will contain a string with a name matching a property in the object.

Comment: Do your entity have a `name` public property?

Comment: No, do I need that? I'm not calling a property called name, in the code I posted it's just a placeholder for the actual name of a property. I just set the variable equal to name to simplify it.

Comment: So my question is about the actual code. Please post a code that reproduce the problem. Your code should contains a simple entity class. Also the code you actually try to get the property name.  Also another thing you should clarify more about, is if the return value is null or you receive a null reference exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
var result = object.GetType().InvokeMember(
    "YourPropertyNameHere",
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty,
    null,
    object,
    null);
```

Info on InvokeMember...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Tutorial on C# Reflection...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial

Comment: Ok, this worked! I'm fairly new and don't understand the difference between this and my code. Can you give me a brief explanation or point me in the right direction with a topic that explains it? Thanks

Comment: You use InvokeMember to actually call the reflected properties and methods dynamically. Never used GetValue, so I have no idea what its intended use is. Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial), it should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Weird...this worked fine for me.  I assume in both places where you have "object", you're putting the name of your object variable?

One thing I noticed was that the property name is case-sensitive, but if I didn't match case in my call to GetProperty(), I got a NullReferenceException, not a null value.

Comment: Yes, I tried to simplify the code i posted. object represents an instance of an entity class. I already made sure the case matches, so that's not an issue for me.